# Display Random images using a foreach loop and and one < img > tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have set of Images. I want to display images Randomly. Inside for-each loop I'm calling images. Suppose I have 10 records and therefore 10 images should be display randomly from given set of images in side the script. But the problem is only a one image will display and rest of images wont visible. loop working fine. Is getElementById can use for one id only once?? please I need a help to solve this matter and where I made wrong.

This is the code.

```
<script>
    var myPix = new Array("/Contents/img/CarrerGuide/office-1.png",
        "/Contents/img/CarrerGuide/office-2.png",
        "/Contents/img/CarrerGuide/office-3.png",
        "/Contents/img/CarrerGuide/office-4.png",
        "/Contents/img/CarrerGuide/office-5.png",
        "/Contents/img/CarrerGuide/office-6.png",
        "/Contents/img/CarrerGuide/office-7.png",
        "/Contents/img/CarrerGuide/office-8.png",
        "/Contents/img/CarrerGuide/office-9.png",
        "/Contents/img/CarrerGuide/office-10.png");

    var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * myPix.length);
    document.getElementById("myPicture").src = myPix[randomNum];
</script>

@{ var counter = 1; }
    <tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <td>
            <img id="myPicture" name="myPicture" alt="some image"  class="img-responsive">
            item.jobPosition
        </td>

        if (counter % 3 == 0)  //Display 3 courses at a row
        {
            @:</tr><tr>
        }
        counter++;
    }
```

Comment: `randomNum` is created only once, not in loop!

Comment: `id` should be unique, you're creating 10 `img` with the same `id` so each `img` gets the same picture

Comment: get elements by `$('.img-responsive')` and set image for each element in loop!

Comment: @depperm problem is even i didnt get same picture 10 times. image displays only once and rest are wont display.

Comment: @RayonDabre I didn't got what you said. Can you explain me the code how it should be please. :)

Comment: sorry, correction jquery uses `document.getElementById` which will return the first element with said `id` not multiple

Comment: Its not clear what your wanting to do. You have 10 images. Do you want each table cell to have a different image (10 cells, 10 different images) or do you want them to be random (some cells may have duplicates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You will have to select all the elements having attribute names as `$('[name=\'myPicture\']')` and iterate them to change `src` of each element. In your example, you are not getting `randomNum` for each element.
>
> Also note that you should not have same `is`s for multiple elements in same document!

```js
var myPix = ["/Contents/img/CarrerGuide/office-1.png",
  "/Contents/img/CarrerGuide/office-2.png",
  "/Contents/img/CarrerGuide/office-3.png",
  "/Contents/img/CarrerGuide/office-4.png",
  "/Contents/img/CarrerGuide/office-5.png",
  "/Contents/img/CarrerGuide/office-6.png",
  "/Contents/img/CarrerGuide/office-7.png",
  "/Contents/img/CarrerGuide/office-8.png",
  "/Contents/img/CarrerGuide/office-9.png",
  "/Contents/img/CarrerGuide/office-10.png"
];
$('[name=\'myPicture\']').each(function() {
  var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * myPix.length);
  this.src = myPix[randomNum];
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Rayon Dabre. This is what I expected. thanks a lot.